# Adding stuff to the navigation bar

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I want to add some stuff to the navigation bar (like Heading and some buttons like back or home, a shopping cart and a Youtube ENDO channel) at the top of the view. But navigation bar is not visible in the nib file. That can be done through some coding stuff. So, how can I add them to navigation bar??
Please help

regards
Prateek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your view controller to a `UINavigationController` first. There are two scenarios:

Either, from your root controller. Just look at the template "Navigation based Application" in Xcode / New Project for how to do this. Most things just happen automatically. When you push a view controller, it should already have a navigation bar. Also, you will find it in your xib file.

Or, from another view controller that is not part of a navigation controller. Before pushing it, "wrap" it into a navigation controller like this:

```
 MyViewController *controller = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
 UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] 
    initWithRootViewController:controller];
 [self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
 [controller release];
 [nav release];
```

Now you can add to `self.navigationController.navigationBar` to your heart's content.

Comment: hello mundi
actually I have already added a pushviewcontroller. I want to add more buttons and a heading to it. is is showing a navigation bar in the simulator but not in the xib file.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such thing as a "pushViewController". Click on the **Navigation Controller** in the xib file. It should have sub-items like the navigationBar and navigationItems. You can add `UIBarButtonItems` to it. These can also be added programmatically. In addition you can add subviews to the navigation bar, but not directly. Check out "Updating the Navigation Bar" in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UINavigationController).